# TextBlob For Extracting Noun Phrases: WordList issue

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, textblob

I'm hoping someone can help me. I am working with a relatively large dataframe (1.4m rows) containing repair ticket text.

An example:

```
"water tank in loft area may be leaking according to op that went out for roofing issue as damp patches on ceilings all upstairs"
```

I have been able to apply TextBlob to extract the noun phrases. Each row has a different job description. There is a Noun_Phrase column with the extracted noun phrases, which will vary in number depending on the job description. There may be no noun phrases up to several.

E.g.

Noun Phrases from above job description would be:

```
['water tank','loft area','damp patches']
```

I want to look at the frequency of how often each noun phrase occurs across the 1.4 million observations. To start with I need to get them into a single list of phrases (not spread across several columns).

I've tried:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['Noun_Phrases'].values.tolist())
```

Intended output:

df2:

```
Index  |  Noun_Phrase
0      |  water tank
1      |  loft area
2      |  damp patches
```

However this produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['Noun_Phrases'].values.tolist())
>
> File
>   "C:\Users[Redacted]\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 387, in **init**
>       arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users[Redacted]\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 7434, in _to_arrays
>       dtype=dtype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users[Redacted]\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 7511, in _list_to_arrays
>       content = list(lib.to_object_array(data).T)
>
> File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1524, in
>   pandas._libs.lib.to_object_array
>
> TypeError: Expected list, got WordList

I'm new to Python and NLP, so figuring things out on the fly. There doesn't seem to be many posts concerning how to deal with WordLists. Perhaps there is a better approach that hasn't occurred to me.

Comment: Jon, Will you be able to provide  initial few line of the DataFrame(`df`)  of yours.

Comment: I am new to this but earlier it said I'm too new to add an image. Basically the headings are "Job Number" (a unique ID), "Job Description" (such as the example given), "Date" (when the repair was reported), "Property ID" (a unique ID identifying the asset the repair job relates to). Then a new column called "Noun_Phrases" as per the example above.

Comment: The code used to get the noun phrases was: df['Noun_Phrases'] = df['Job_Description'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).noun_phrases)

Comment: df2 results from the code that extracts the noun phrases, so does not exist. df is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. In Spyder variable explorer df is a DataFrame (1388790,9)

Comment: pls also try `df['Noun_Phrases'] = df['Job_Description'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x.strip()).noun_phrases)`    i have changed it little bit used `strip()`

Comment: I'd like to but each time I try, it asks me to import an image. It then says because I am too inexperienced on this site, that it won't show an embedded image.

Comment: can't it be Just copy paste text format few lines.

Comment: The key data is the job description and noun phrases. Example job descriptions: 1) 'floor boards - creaking in the bedroom. 2) please assess
all water coming from water tank in loft smells bad, previous issue tech team advised raise plumbing inspection  3) tile around bath broken - sharp edges. replace with single white tile. 4) cold water tap on mixer on kitchen sink only comes out a trickle. trace and remedy. Associated noun_phrases are 1) ['floor boards'], 2) ['water tank', 'loft smells', 'previous issue tech team'],  3) ['mixer tap', 'sharp edges', 'white tile'] 4) ['cold water tap']